# "The operating system denied access to the specified file" in Cygwin bash

Tags: cygwin

```
d@Desktop /cygdrive/c/users/test/otherfolder
$ cygstart --action=runas ping -c 1 www.google.com | grep 'bytes from' | cut -d
 = -f 4
Unable to start 'ping': The operating system denied access to the specified file
.

d@Desktop /cygdrive/c/users/test/otherfolder
$
```

I am trying to run some scripts on cygwin, but I can't get those script running for some reasons. I tried to run as administrator, I also tried using `cygstart --action=runas`, but nothing seems to work. Any idea?

Comment: Is `ping` the Windows command, the Cygwin command, or your own script?

Comment: It's a windows command I think.

Comment: Can you run `ping` from a command line? What does `type -a ping` tell you (from a Cygwin bash shell prompt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod 755 ping` to set the permissions of the file. Should work.

Comment: Assuming that's the solution, `777` is excessive; there's no reason to give write access to everyone. `755` makes more sense. But if `ping` is a command provided either by Windows or by Cygwin, messing with its permissions is likely to be a bad idea.